# JDBC/Resultset error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, limit, max

My mysql-query in Java always stops (i.e. freezes and does not continue) at a certain position, which namely is 543,858; even though the table contains approx. 2,000,000 entries. I've checked this by logging the current result-fetching.
It is reproducible and happens every time at the very same position.

```
"SELECT abc from bcd WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), timestamp) <= '"+days+"'");
```

Addition: It definitely **is** a Java error, I've just tried out this statement in Navicat (50s running time).

The query seems to freeze after the log tells me that it's now adding the result of position 543,858.

```
try {
    ...
    ResultSet res = new ResultSet();
    PreparedStatement stmt = new PreparedStatement(); // prepare statmenet etc.
    stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    res = stmt.executeQuery();
    ...
    System.out.println(res.getStatement());
    ...
    while (res.next())
        treeSet.add(res.getString("userid"));

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit: We were able to figure out the problem. This method is fine and the returned result (500,000 instead of 2,000,000) is right as well (looked up in the wrong db to verify the amount); the problem was, that the next method-call that used the result of the one posted above takes literally forever, but had no logging-implemented. So I've been fooled by missing console-logs.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stops"? (Note that you should be using parameterized SQL for various reasons, too.) It would help if you could show your code.

Comment: This is very much impossible to diagnose without seeing some Java first.

Comment: @user1004816 better paste your code in the question

Comment: @soulcheck: okay, sorry.

Comment: I agree with oers. I think you should use `setFetchSize(0);`

Comment: Unfortunately, stmt.setFetchSize(0) doesn't change anything. @soulcheck: I don't know, this is actually administrated by other coworkers.

Comment: The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row. After this any result sets created with the statement will be retrieved row-by-row. (MySQL Manual)

Comment: @user1004816 if setFetchSize(0) changed anything, it would be probably for worse, as 0 is the default value, and the driver would try to stuff 2 * 10^6 records in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be running out of memory after processing half a million records. Try assigning more memory using command line options `-Xmx` etc. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#options) for more info about command line options.

Comment: If I'd be running outta memory Java would probably throw an exception; the program is started with 2048 to 4096MB, otherwise it won't even execute.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql to use streaming ResultSets you have to specify more parameters, not only fetchSize.

Try:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement('select ...', java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

and see if that works.

It's [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) in the ResultSet section.

Strange that it doesn't throw exception, but this is the only suspect I have. Maybe it starts garbage collection/flushes memory to disk and it takes so much time it doesn't get to throw it.

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work either. stmt.setQueryTimeout(180); does not seem to be executed as well, there is neiter a break out of he loop nor an exception.

Comment: @user1004816 what happens if you only iterate through resultset without adding records to the treeSet?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would try to add to your query " LIMIT 543857" and then " LIMIT 543857" and see what happens.
2. If the above does not help, use the limit directive combined with order by.

I suspect that there is invalid entry in your table and the way to find it is binary search.